# Regex Python: Keep first digits

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

The objective is to keep the first digits in a string, but remove them if they are in different place.

For instance, just this numbers should be kept:

```
123456 AB
123456 GENERAL
123456 HOSPITAL
```

On the other hand, these numbers should be removed:

```
PROJECT 150000 SCHOLARSHIPS
SUMMERLAND 05 100 SCHOOL 100 ABC
ABC HOSPITAL 01 20 30 GENERAL
ABC HOSPITAL 01
```

I have crafted this regex which is very near to the mentioned behaviour and substituting for empty space:

```
(?<=\w\b )([0-9]*)
```

However, I am getting some an additional space when removing the digits which is coming from the preceding space:

```
123456 AB
123456 GENERAL
123456 HOSPITAL

PROJECT  SCHOLARSHIPS
SUMMERLAND   SCHOOL  ABC
ABC HOSPITAL    GENERAL
ABC HOSPITAL
```

How can I get rid of this space?

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'(\w)\s+\d+', r'\1', text)` or `r'(\S)\s+\d+'`. Add `\b` at the end if you only need to remove numbers as whole words. If you want to use a lookbehind, you may use it like ``re.sub(r'(?<=\w)\s+\d+', '', text)``

Comment: Or `^\s*(\d+)|\d+\s*` instead of a lookbehind and replace with group 1 `r\1` https://regex101.com/r/LOsWMK/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the first digits in the string, you could also use a capturing group with an alternation instead of a lookbehind. Capture in a group what you want to keep, and match what you don't want to keep.

```
^([^\S\r\n]*\d+)|\d+[^\S\r\n]*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1** (what you want to keep)

  - `[^\S\r\n]*\d+` Match optional whitespace chars except newlines, match 1+ digits
- `)` Close group
- `|` Or
- `\d+[^\S\r\n]*` Match 1+ digits followed by optional whitespace chars except newlines (What you want to remove)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OShWym/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mWdqnq)

For example

```
result = re.sub(regex, r'\1', test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
```

Output

```
123456 AB
123456 GENERAL
123456 HOSPITAL

PROJECT SCHOLARSHIPS
SUMMERLAND SCHOOL ABC
ABC HOSPITAL GENERAL
ABC HOSPITAL
```

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird, I was looking for getting rid of the look behind, but not sure how. Thanks a lot for showing how :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just include the space in the capturing group like this:

```
(?<=\w\b )([ 0-9]*)
            ^ additional space
```